# Scid: Play Against Computer

Tags: scid

After I set a board up in Scid, how can I get the computer to play as White? I cannot for the life of me figure it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean Scid vs Pc what I do is click on the "flip board" icon - second from right - and then choose the engine from the "Play" menu. It automatically starts playing for white.

Comment: Scid works this way, too